# Validating message(s) in IBM MQ in import and export queues

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I am trying to write 2 methods to test whether the sent message in one queue is received in another queue.

Send method - Sends message, for example - "Message 123" - to export queue with unique correlation id.

Get method

This queue will have many messages, however i want to get only the message that I  sent from above based on my correlation ids.

Code to check message based on correlation id

```
      properties = new Hashtable();
       properties.Add(MQC.CONNECTION_NAME_PROPERTY, "connection name");
       properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, "transport type");
       properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "channel name"); 
       properties.Add(MQC.CONNECT_OPTIONS_PROPERTY, MQC.MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE_BLOCK);



       mqGetMsgOpts = new MQGetMessageOptions();
       mqGetMsgOpts.Options = MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST | MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE;
       mqGetMsgOpts.MatchOptions = MQC.MQMO_MATCH_CORREL_ID;
       mqGetMsgOpts.WaitInterval = 3000; //3 secs wait time
```

The issue am facing is when i read messages, i get all the messages from the import queue.

How do i get only the messages that i sent and validate that the message that is received in the export queue is mine?

Theoretically, something like this

message.correlationid from import queue matches message.correaltionid in the export queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your snippet does not show setting correlId when reading messages. I have this sample code that gets only the message matching given correlId.

Like earlier, your snippet still has `MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE` for `MQGMO`. `MQOO`stands for `Open Options` whereas `MQGMO` stands for `Get message options`

```
        try
        {
            importQ = qm.AccessQueue("Q2", MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED | MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT | MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);

            // Put one message. MQ generates correlid
            MQMessage mqPutMsg = new MQMessage();
            mqPutMsg.WriteString("This is the first message with no app specified correl id");
            importQ.Put(mqPutMsg);

            // Put another messages but with application specified correlation id
            mqPutMsg = new MQMessage();
            mqPutMsg.WriteString("This is the first message with application specified correl id");
            mqPutMsg.CorrelationId = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strCorrelId);
            MQPutMessageOptions mqpmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();
            importQ.Put(mqPutMsg,mqpmo);

            mqPutMsg = new MQMessage();

            // Put another message with MQ generating correlation id
            mqPutMsg.WriteString("This is the second message with no app specified correl id");
            importQ.Put(mqPutMsg);

            // Get only the message that matches the correl id
            MQMessage respMsg = new MQMessage();
            respMsg.CorrelationId = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strCorrelId);
            MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
            gmo.WaitInterval = 3000;
            gmo.Options = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT;
            gmo.MatchOptions = MQC.MQMO_MATCH_CORREL_ID;

            importQ.Get(respMsg, gmo);
            Console.WriteLine(respMsg.ReadString(respMsg.MessageLength));
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, i did the same way as you mentioned, however i keep getting either one of this error.

IBM.WMQ.MQException: MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE


System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Unable to read beyond the end of the stream. -> the message leaves the queue and it throws this due to data length becoming 0, any thoughts?

Comment: MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE: Check your code for match options and correlId while getting messages. It looks like the correlId specified may not be matching correlid of any of the message in the queue. EndOfStreamException: Appears to be attempting to read a data of an empty message.